# YouTube iframe embed showinfo not working in chrome but working in IE and FF

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, youtube, embedding

This isn't even an issue specific to a site I'm trying to make, as you can go to https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo to replicate the issue.
Simply play the standard video without changing any options, and then untick the showinfo setting to try and remove the title, play the video again with the updated setting, and the title is still there.

Any way to fix this?