# Can't use "showinfo=0" in YouTube embed

Tags: youtube

I know this might be a possible repost of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670901/adding-showinfo-0-to-youtube-iframe-doesnt-always-work), but since that post didn't get any replies, I'm giving it another shot. I'm trying to embed a YouTube video where I want to hide the title and the share buttons at the top. The [YouTube IFrame Player API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters) lists `showinfo` as a valid parameter that could be set to either `0` or `1`, where `0` hides the title and `1` shows it.

So one would think that `<iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/v8_fEQOOMp0?showinfo=0"></iframe>` would be possible. However, when I try this, it isn't working. The title still shows:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bf9qou8k/)

Other parameters like `controls=0` and `autoplay=1` are working fine. And what's interesting, the title is hidden when I try the JSFiddle above in Safari. So I'm just wondering. Does this have to do with the browser version? That some browsers ignores that parameter while others don't? I'm using **Chrome 63.0.3239.132**. Or is this a change that YouTube have decided on without updating the docs? Have I missed something?

Comment: Seems to be a Chrome-specific issue, wasn't able to reproduce on Firefox.

Comment: @JacobWood It's so strange that this problem isn't solved after such a long time: [YouTube iframe embed showinfo not working in chrome but working in IE and FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459547/youtube-iframe-embed-showinfo-not-working-in-chrome-but-working-in-ie-and-ff)

Answer (score 3):

showinfo is deprecated
check this link
https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomlashack/upcoming-changes-in-osyoutube/

Comment: But it wasn't at the time the question was asked, that is weird